# Creating an android app and a web server compatible with sql server database

Tags: android, sql, database

I am attempting to create a web server that can receive query info from an android app, retrieve the info from the sql database and then send the data to the android app over the internet. The android app then needs to be able to update data on a different sql database (same web server?).

I am new to database programming and have zero experience in mobile apps. So far I have created an asp page with the LINQ to SQL template in visual studio. This can display a table but I don't know if I'm really heading in the right direction for the web server with query capatibilities. Also, would hosting the server on a site like godaddy be the correct thing to do in this case?

As for the android app, I have seen many questions regarding sql communication but I'm not to the point on the app where the info will be useful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you might need to use any kind of web service to connect a mobile app to a database, you can't do it "directly" like you can on web apps or desktop apps. For example, I use WCF to register data on my MySQL database from my phonegap build app (mobile app designed with html5, css and JS) which works in android, iOS, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will research how to use WCF. Do you think it would be necessary/helpful to use phonegap vs Eclipse/java?

Comment: I use phonegap which allows you to create "native" apps with html 5, css and js for almost every plataform. You don't need to learn either java for android or objective c for iOS, you can use html, css, js instead. It also allows you to use GPS, camera, contacts, and other kinds of information from the device. The performance is not the same as a native app, but imho its good enough. Here's the link: http://www.phonegap.com

Comment: Ok, the fact is I know java and C# but not html, css, or js. And the only feature I need to use is internet for the data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I got it all figured out.